# Deserialize json objects/arrays

Tags: c#, json.net

I have following JSON response from a webserver which i am trying to Deserialize into something i can work with in my C# code.

```
{
"sprints": [
    {
        "id": 377,
        "sequence": 377,
        "name": "Sprint 1",
        "state": "CLOSED",
        "linkedPagesCount": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 354,
        "sequence": 354,
        "name": "Sprint 2",
        "state": "CLOSED",
        "linkedPagesCount": 0
    }
],
"velocityStatEntries": {
    "354": {
        "estimated": {
            "value": 19,
            "text": "19.0"
        },
        "completed": {
            "value": 15,
            "text": "15.0"
        }
    },
    "377": {
        "estimated": {
            "value": 21,
            "text": "21.0"
        },
        "completed": {
            "value": 19,
            "text": "19.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above seems to be an array (sprints) then an object(velocityStatEntries) -> object(for example 354) -> Object(estimated) and Object(completed).

I tried to Deserialize with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(t);` but i get an exception :

Additional information: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path 'velocityStatEntries', line 1, position 630.

which is obvious because it doesn't understand that there is an array then there is something else. Can i somehow specify what kind of data i have without making the full structure in code like classes ?

/donnib

Answer (score 0):

latest json.net version allows you to do this:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:10, str:'string', array: [1,2,3]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```

output:

```
 10
 string
 3
```

Documentation here: **[LINQ to JSON with Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

You have quite some ways:

You can take Lists for JSON Arrays and Dictionaries for JSON Objects.

```
List<Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,object>>>>
```

You can explicitly define your data structure using object classes:

```
public class Sprint {
    public int id;
    public int sequence;
    public string name;
    public string state;
    public int linkedPagesCount;
}

public class Sth {
    public Sprint[] sprints;
    ...
}

new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Sth>(mySthVariable)
```

You can use `dynamic` data type.

You can mix up two of them or even all three to a steaming hot code soup.